# PHP Codeigniter - Undefined property on controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and the version I am using is the latest [Codeigniter v2.1.4](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter).

I am doing some simple CRUD as a start for making my own web blog but it's getting an error message on my controller as following.

> Message: Undefined property: Site::$site_model

Controller

```
function blog() {
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->site_model->get_records();

        if (isset($query)) {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $data['main_content'] = 'blog';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
```

It's complaining on this line `$query = $this->site_model->get_records();`

Model

```
function get_records() {
        $query = $this->db->get('data');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

db library is loaded as well..

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you load your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before that you need to `load the model` like

```
$data = array();
$this->load->model('site_model');   //Here
$query = $this->site_model->get_records();
```

When ever you are dealing with the model functions makesure that before that you need to load the model as well.

As **Hashem Qolami** said you can auto load the model like

```
$autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');
```

But in my opinion auto loading of all the models may create some performance issues(Iam not sure) but you can do this.

Comment: Also you can load essential models by: `$autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');`

Comment: yes you are right Hashem Qolami but I think its not the beter option to load each model using autoload.

Comment: That was super fast! The tutorial I followed is for the old version and this is probably one of things that changed. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Gautam3164 Absolutely, I said `essential models` not each one ;)

Comment: @SeongLee Believe me, there's no sensible different between 2.1.3 and 2.1.4, just some XSS filtering improvement ;)

Comment: @Hashem Qolami Hi, the tutorial I followed was based on version 1.7.1. I did not say 2.1.3. Thanks for the heads up anyways!

Comment: @SeongLee OIC, I just thought you mean the previous version, sorry.